# Sending a Association array with jQuery $.Post

Tags: jquery, jquery-post

This will most likely be a easy question for all you experts!

I have a associative array EX:

```
var ProfInfo= new Array();
ProfInfo['action'] = 'SaveNewProfile'; 
ProfInfo['other'] = 'moreStuff';
ProfInfo['oth'] = 'More Stuff';
```

and I need to send this array with a jQuery post. Currently I've tried the following:

```
$.post("ajax/ProfileMod.php", {
action:'SaveNewProfile',
data:ProfInfo}
, function(data, status) {
if(status == "success") {
// POST AJAX Script succesful
alert (data);

} else {
// POST AJAX Script error
alert ('AJAX POST error : Error saving New profile in ProfileMod.php');
}
});  // End AJAX POST Call
```

I can get the 'action' in the php $_POST, but not the associative array. So then I tried the following:

```
ProfInfo['action'] = 'SaveNewProfile'; // Add the action type in he array to pass
$.post("ajax/ProfileMod.php", ProfInfo
, function(data, status) {
if(status == "success") {
// POST AJAX Script succesful
    alert (data);
} else {
// POST AJAX Script error
    alert ('AJAX POST error : Error saving New profile in ProfileMod.php');
}
});  // End AJAX POST Call
```

And in this case I don't get anything at all. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, [`new Array()` instances](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) can be *abused* and treated as associative arrays (aka  objects), but you *should* construct `ProfInfo` [like this instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers):

```
var ProfInfo = {};
```

Comment: Thank You! It work right away! I'm new to Javascript and it a special learning curve!